# Assembly language: AL=max(AL,BL,CL)

Tags: assembly, max, x86-16, emu8086

I have to calculate the max value from 3 values using registers, and store the max value in `AL`. It is required to use jumps and compares.
For example I wrote how to determine the max value from 2 numbers, but I can't do it using 3.

```
mov bl,1
mov cl,2
cmp bl,cl
jg label1   ;jump if greater
mov al,bl   ;al keeps the maximum
jmp stop

  label1: mov al,bl
  stop:nop;
```

I should do the `AL=max(AL,BL,CL)` after this model.

Comment: Do it in pseudo  code first, so you can see the logic that is needed. Then do that in asm.

Comment: You can overwrite one of the input registers, like BL=max(BL,CL) as the first step, leaving AL untouched, and saving instructions because you only need a MOV at all if BL wasn't already greater or equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your code will always report `BL` for greatest! The line `mov al,bl   ;al keeps the maximum` should read `mov al, cl`.

For `AL=max(AL,BL,CL)`, first find the max between `AL` and `BL` and keep it in `AL` that is to be modified anyway as it will be the result. Then find the max between the possibly new `AL` and `CL` yielding the final `AL`:

```
  cmp al, bl
  jg  OK1
  mov al, bl
OK1:
  cmp al, cl
  jg  OK2
  mov al, cl
OK2:
  ; AL is max(AL,BL,CL)
```

This way registers `BL` and `CL` are not modified, if that's important.